# I downloaded something from safari called blue stacks it doesn't go away

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

[image]

the blue stacks app didn't end up working instead there's this bar that says "Verifying blue stacks installer" Nothing I do gets rid of it. I can't 'x' it out I can only minimize it.

Comment: Did you try disconnecting the internet?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, you can reboot normally and if the disk to the BlueStacks is still mounted you can them unmount it in Finder and remove the .dmg file from your downloads. This sometimes happens, might be a bug, I generally just restart the Finder process but I wouldn't recommend that to everyone, so rebooting is the way.

(If you already installed it and want to remove the app and any files associated you should consider [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), it's totally free)